# is there a collocation "have as a goal + Noun"

Tags: collocations

I came across the sentence below and I've never found that phrase which is bold.

> Formerly, person who retired from the world in order to form utopians
> had **as their goal the setting up of perfect communities**

Thank you !

Comment: What about it don't you understand? Also, can you please cite the source of that sentence? It's also missing an article ("*a* person").

Comment: You asked about the following sentence, "*Formerly, person who retired from the world in order to form utopians had as their goal the setting up of perfect communities.*" The sentence is not written in standard American English. There are several pieces of grammar which are unconventional. If we re-write the sentence, we have: "*There once was a person who chose to retire from the world. This person wanted to form utopian societies. Their goal was to set up perfect communities.*"

Comment: Also, I believe it should read, "utopias" (without the "n"), as a "utopian" is a person, and you don't "make" people.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I converted your answer to a comment because it's helpful, but it's a comment about the form of the question and doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I don't think you're using "collocation" correctly. Are you asking whether the *structure* * [ "have as a goal" + noun ]* is *correct* and natural grammar?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon - The version _Formerly, people who retired from the world in order to set up utopias had as their goal the setting up of perfect communities_ is closer to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we say *they had [something] as their goal*. In this case the 'something' is a six-word phrase, so the sentence reads better if it is placed at the end - *they had as their goal [something].*